# warning: type of ‘n’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int] warning in 'gcc' , but no warning in 'clang'

Tags: c, gcc, clang, warnings

I've written a simple code to print **n** numbers recursively:

```
  1 #include<stdio.h>
  2 
  3 void print(n)
  4 {
  5 printf("%d\t", n);
  6 if(n>=1)
  7     {
  8 print(n-1);
  9     }
 10     
 11 return;
 12 }
 13 
 14 
 15 int main()
 16 {
 17 int n;
 18 
 19 print(6);
 20 
 21return 0;
 22 }
```

It is compiled without any warning by *clang*, but *gcc* complains and I get the warning:

```
warning: type of ‘n’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
```

The code is executed flawlessly even when it's compiled by *gcc*. I want to know:

- Why do I get the warning?
- Why do compilers behave differently?

P.S.
I use these command to compile them:

> cc 1.c -o 1

> clang 1.c -o 1

compilers' version:

> clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
> gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
> 9.3.0

Comment: Please change `void print(n)` to `void print(int n)` to be fully defined. You did not define the type of `n` so gcc reminds you it had to make an assumption.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks I forgot the int , but why doesn't clang complain?

Comment: The warning level set? As it happens, my MS Visual C warns about the unused `int n` in `main()` but not about the default function argument type.

Comment: How do you invoke the compilers? `gcc source.c` and `clang source.c`? What are the version of your compilers?

Comment: - clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
- gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

Comment: --clang 1.c -o 1    ---gcc 1.c -o 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compiler conforming to the C standard must issue a diagnostic for the missing declaration, per the constraint in C 2018 6.9.1 6 (bold and footnotes are mine):

> If the declarator includes an identifier list<sup>1</sup>, each declaration in the declaration list<sup>2</sup> shall have at least one declarator, those declarators shall declare only identifiers from the identifier list, and **every identifier in the identifier list shall be declared**…

A declarator for `n` in the declaration list would be the appearance of `n` in a declaration such as `int n;`. Since there is none, this violates the constraint, and a conforming compiler must issue a diagnostic (per 5.1.1.3 1).

Clang’s default mode is not conforming to the C standard. You can request better adherence with `-pedantic`, after which Clang reports:

```
warning: parameter 'n' was not declared, defaulting to type 'int'
```

I suggest using at least the switches `-Wmost -Werror -pedantic -O3 -std=c17`.

I also prefer `-Wno-shift-op-parentheses -Wno-logical-op-parentheses`.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> An identifier list is a list of identifiers for function parameters, without types. The `n` in `void print(n)` is an identifier list.

<sup>2</sup> A declaration list is a list of declarations after the `)` that ends the function parameters and before the `{` that starts the function body. The declaration list for the `print` function in the code in the question is empty.